# golang runtime error: index out of range

Tags: go, panic

I have a simple for loop in go which iterates through a slice of integers and changes the position of the current if next is smaller basically a sort, but it keeps showing me this error which says

```
panic: runtime error: index out of range
```

Here is the code:

```
func sort(n int, l []int) interface{} {
    fmt.Println(l)
    if d == false {
        d = true
        for i := range l {
            n := i + 1
            t := l[i]
            l[i] = l[n]
            l[n] = t
            arr = l
            d = false
        }
        return sort(n, arr)
    }
    return arr
}
```

Returned arr is declared as a global variable.
Here is the error:

```
panic: runtime error: index out of range

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.troubleSort(0x5, 0xc42001a150, 0x5, 0x5, 0x0, 0xc42000e1d0)
        /home/julkreshpaj/codejam/Trouble Sort/Solution.go:21 +0x1c1
main.main()
        /home/julkreshpaj/codejam/Trouble Sort/Solution.go:60 +0x82
exit status 2
```

Comment: What is the complete error message, with line number? And which line in your code does it correspond to?

Comment: Put the error in the question. But more important: *read* the error. It tells you were your problem is.

Comment: line 21 is ```l[i] = l[n]``` and line 60 is where function is called in main

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to access `l[n]` where `n := i + 1`, and `i` is the index of `l`.  This means that on the last time through the loop, when `i` is the last element in `l`, `n` will always be past the last element of `l`. Every time.

Comment: i thought that but is there a fix that i can make

Comment: @JulKreshpaj, `for i := 0; i < len(l) - 1; i++ {}`